# Mac Bash Script: For every multiple of 7 open a terminal window & type command

Tags: bash, macos

Essentially all I have is a loop from 0-1000, but I want to make it so that every time a number is a multiple of 7 occurs, open a terminal window and type the following lines:

1. cd desktop/testfolder
2. node testScript.js
3. 7 <---- the multiple of 7 goes here

**So for example if the loop gets to 49 the commands would be:**

1. cd desktop/testfolder
2. node testScript.js
3. 49

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nocasematch
read -p " Execute script? (y/n): " response
if [[ $response == y ]]; then
    printf " Loading....\\n"
    for ((x = 0; x<1000; x++)); do

      #add a check if x is a multiple of 7 here...

      printf " Open %s Terminal\\n" $x
      osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd desktop//testfolder\
node myScript.js\
MULTIPLE OF 7 HERE"' >/dev/null

    done
fi
shopt -u nocasematch
```

I have got the terminal opening & first two commands sorted but I can't figure out how to add a check for **x** to make sure its a multiple of 7, and I can't work out how to get the x integer into the terminal "do script" string.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: From your question, it is not clear to me whether you have trouble testing that a number is a multiple of 7, or how to pass such a number to `oascript`. Please answer exactly one question at one time. Post several questions if you have several problems.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```sh
   for ((x = 0; x<1000; x++)); do

      #add a check if x is a multiple of 7 here...
```

you can do:

```sh
for ((x = 0; x<1000; x=x+7)); do
```

Also, in order to provide this string, if I get correctly what you try to do

```
tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd desktop//testfolder\
node myScript.js\
7"
```

you can do this, in the bash shell:

```
str="tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd desktop//testfolder\\
node myScript.js\\
$x\""
osascript -e "$str"
```

Comment: I have tried that command part you mentioned however that does not work in this case because it needs to be in the format: osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "$x"'

Comment: I have tried that command part you mentioned however that does not work in this case because the $x part is already in some double quotes as part of the script. What you are suggesting I do is:

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd desktop\\"$x\""' 

which does not work. I am trying to pass the variable into the do script string

Comment: Neither of those work unfortunately. All I'm trying to do is replace $x in the following string with the x integer: 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd desktop//testfolder\node myScript.js\$x"'

So for example it would be: 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd desktop//testfolder\node myScript.js\7"'

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work using @thanasisp's `for ((x = 0; x<1000; x=x+7)); do`

And then to get the $x in the do script string I did the following:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd desktop//testfolder\
node myScript.js\
'$x'"'
```

Just got a bit confusing with all the single and double quotes I guess...